# I want to fire custom validation for complex log inspite of having empty value in the field

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement in asp.net, that either email id or mobile has to be entered & I have custom validator on server side to check for duplicate. My problem is when I keep email id & mobile id blank it's not firing my custom validator(which is as per microsoft design). If I am putting requiredfield validator for email & phone it mandates the user to enter both of them which I don't want. Is there any way I can achieve my requirement.

Here is my custom validator code:

```
protected void EmailCheckValidation_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            if (txtEmail.Text.Trim() == "" || txtMobile.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                return;
            }
            args.IsValid = !DatabaseManager.DALHelper.IsEmailExists(txtEmail.Text);
        }
```

Comment: first check on the clientside on form submission, if both fields are empty , then don't submit the form.

Comment: Have you called Page.Validate, or is your control that you've bound the custom validator have the CausesValidation property set to true?

Comment: yes I have Page.Validate which returns me false. Custom validators are getting fired if I don't keep the textfields blank